# DRYing up these helper methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've got three methods like this:

```
def total_fat
  total = 0
  meal_foods = current_user.meal_foods
  meal_foods.each do |food|
    total += food.fat
  end
  return total
end
```

One for fat, carbs, and protein.

I'd like to DRY this up.

I've tried this method and it didn't seem to work by passing in the 'macro' as string.

```
def total_of(macro)
  total = 0
  meal_foods = current_user.meal_foods
  meal_foods.each do |food|
    total += food.macro
  end
  return total 
end
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def total_of(marcro)
  current_user.meal_foods.map(&marcro).inject(:+)
end
```

This takes the Array(-like) collection of `meal_foods` and maps it to an Array of just the `marcro` value of the `meal_foods`, and then injects a "+" between each of the numbers.  Make sure to pass the argument as a symbol, e.g. `total_of(:fat)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def total_of(type)
  current_user.meal_foods.map(&:type).sum
end
```

total_of(:fat)

Comment: `Array#sum` requires ActiveSupport.  Although the question has Rails tags, the question itself could be a pure Ruby one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use send to invoke methods with variables, and convert macro to a symbol.

so:

```
  food.send(macro.to_sym)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def total_of(macro)
  current_user.meal_foods.inject(0) do |total,food|
    total + food.send(macro)
  end
end
```

I'm not certain this will work as you've provided no data to try it with, but have a look at [the Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html) docs to give you some ideas of what can be done. `each_with_object` is underused and would fit here too.

There's no need for the explicit return. In fact, there's no need to even mention `total` as it will be the last expression evaluated.